# How to calculate subnet of your interface based on the destination IP and subnet?

Tags: linux, networking, router, ip, subnet

I am new to networking and linux so I am not able to fix this problem. I have a power controller connected to my linux PC (eth0) through a switch with the default static IP of 192.168.1.100 and subnet mask of 255.255.0.0. 
My eth0 interface IP is currently 192.168.1.204 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 but I am not able to ping the power controller.

Can anyone tell me why it is not pinging? should the subnet mask of my PC be different? What should it be so that I can ping it?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... Where to start...

A) Will that powercontroller actually respond to pings at all ? That is not a given.
B) The subnetmask (255.255.255.0 or 255.255.0.0) doesn't matter in this particular case as both ip-addresses are in the same 255.255.255.0 sub-range of 255.255.0.0. You ought to set the Linux PC to 255.255.0.0 to do it "right".
C) Are you sure the switch is putting both devices in the same LAN ? Smart switches can put some of their ports in 1 LAN and some others ports in another LAN. (Google VLAN for more info.) They will have to be in the same LAN in order to be able to see each other.
D) Are you sure both devices actually have a good connection to the switch ? Are the link-LEDs burning? No errors/warnings ?
E) With "the default static IP of 192.168.1.100" I hope you mean the default IP of the powercontroller, not the switch.
F) Are you sure the switch itself (or any other device connected to it) isn't by chance using either 192.168.1.100 or 192.168.1.204, thereby causing a conflict ?

Lot's of thing can be wrong here (I probably missed some). You will have to check them one by one.

Comment: You may also need to connect to the switch console and see if it is configured correctly for the ports you are using.  Also trying pinging from the switch to the powercontroller if your switch OS supports the ping command.